# How to insert row by row values in single submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my view Page

[image]

This is Dynamically fields Test Name and units are from Table I need to insert Test name and Result and Normal value also Unit.

My Controller

```
 $patient_id = $this->input->post('patient_id');
                        $doctor_id = $this->input->post('doctor_id');
                        $prescription_id = $this->input->post('prescription_id'); 
                        $lab_result =$this->input->post('lab_result');
                        $lab_test =$this->input->post('lab_test');
                        $units =$this->input->post('units');
                       $normal_value =$this->input->post('normal_value');
                       $cat_id = $this->input->post('cat_id');

     for($i=0; $i<count($prescription_id); $i++)
           {
                    $labreport[] = array(
                       'patient_id' => $patient_id[$i],
                       'doctor_id' => $doctor_id[$i],
                       'prescription_id' =>$prescription_id[$i],
                       'lab_result'   => $lab_result[$i],
                       'lab_test'     => $lab_test[$i],
                       'units'        =>  $units[$i],
                       'normal_value' => $normal_value[$i],
                       'cat_id' => $cat_id, );
                      //echo '<pre>'; print_r($labreport); '</pre>'; exit; 
                         }
                       $stringlabreport= json_encode($labreport);
                         $this->db->insert('patient_lab_report',$stringlabreport); 
                          if($this->db->affected_rows()){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Lab Report  Added Successfully');
                          redirect('laboratory_report/all');

 =========================
```

And This is  My View Code

```
 <tr>   
                            <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data->name; ?>"name="lab_test[]"><?php echo $data->name; ?></td>                        
                            <td><input type="text" value=""        name="lab_result[]" class="form-control"></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data->units; ?>"    name="units[] "> <?php echo $data->units; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $data->n_value; ?>" name="normal_value[] "> <?php echo $data->n_value; ?></td>
                        </tr>
```

Comment: Where's your controller and model?

Comment: Welcome to SO, share what you have tried so far. share your code, so we can help you.

Comment: @kesavan can you please edit the question and add controller code and model code

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use array names for input. I.E.:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="someform">
    <input name="row[0][test_name]"/>
    <input name="row[0][result]"/>
    <input name="row[1][test_name]"/>
    <input name="row[1][result]"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submitted" value="send">
</form>
```

So upon submission, parsing in php, use `filter_input` with `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY` as option:

```
<?php

$submitted = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submitted');
if(!empty($submitted)){

    $rows = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'row',  FILTER_DEFAULT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
    $parsed_rows = [];
    foreach($rows as $row){
        if(!empty($row['test_name']) && !empty($row['result'])){
            $parsed_rows[] = $row;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: @kesavan please, provide this as part of your question